# Haskell parentheses

Tags: haskell

Could anyone help me correcting and understanding why the syntax of the following is **not** working? I suppose it's a problem of parentheses.

```
findMinMaxRec smallest largest myList
  | myList == [] = [smallest, largest]
  | head myList < smallest && head myList > largest = findMinMaxRec head myList head myList tail myList 
  | head myList < smallest = findMinMaxRec head myList largest tail myList 
  | head myList > largest = findMinMaxRec smallest head myList tail myList 
  | otherwise = findMinMaxRec smallest largest tail myList

findMinMax [] = []
findMinMax [x] = findMinMaxRec head [x] head [x] [x]
```

Thanks

Comment: You really make it terribly complex and unreadable by using `head` everywhere instead of proper pattern matching :(

Comment: Issues with `head`/`tail` (which should almost never be used) aside, make sure you always use type signatures and think about code in terms of _types of subexpressions_.

Comment: In the future, include the compiler errors in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findMinMaxRec head myList head myList tail myList` means “call `findMinMaxRec` with 6 arguments: `head`, `myList`, `head`, `myList`, `tail`, and `myList`”. You want:

```
findMinMaxRec (head myList) (head myList) (tail myList)
```

However, it would be best to avoid `head` and `tail` here with pattern matching—here’s a slight improvement:

```
findMinMaxRec smallest largest [] = [smallest, largest]
findMinMaxRec smallest largest (x:xs)
  | x < smallest && x > largest = findMinMaxRec x x xs
  | x < smallest = findMinMaxRec x largest xs
  | x > largest = findMinMaxRec smallest x xs
  | otherwise = findMinMaxRec smallest largest xs
```

Likewise, when you write:

```
findMinMax [] = []
findMinMax [x] = findMinMaxRec head [x] head [x] [x]
```

This means `findMinMax` is only defined on 0-element (`[]`) and 1-element (`[x]`) lists; and it has the same problem with parentheses. Another small adjustment:

```
findMinMax [] = []
findMinMax (x:xs) = findMinMaxRec x x xs
```

Finally, since `findMinMaxRec` always returns a two-element list, a tuple would be preferable for the return type; then `findMinMax` can return a `Maybe`.